# How do I securely read the asp.net root configuration folder?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7.5

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine running IIS7.5. This webserver hosts many websites under different domains and each website contains several asp.net applications.
Support and development access to this machine is quite restricted due to customer requirements. I want to use the Microsoft.Web.Administration library to query the configuration of each of these applications in an asmx web method:

```
    [WebMethod(MessageName = "GetDatabases")]
    public List<Connection> GetDatabases()
    {
        List<Connection> connections = new List<Connection>();
        ServerManager sm = new ServerManager();
        foreach (Site site in sm.Sites)
        {
            foreach (Application app in site.Applications)
            {
                System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(app.Path);
                foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cs in config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cs.ConnectionString);
                        connections.Add(new Connection { Site = site.Name, Path = app.Path, Name = cs.Name, InitialCatalog = builder.InitialCatalog, DataSource = builder.DataSource });
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        connections.Add(new Connection { Site = site.Name, Path = app.Path, Name = cs.Name});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return connections;
    }
```

This code runs fine in Visual Studio but once deployed to the server an error occurs:

```
    Server was unable to process request. ---> Filename: redirection.config
    Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
```

I researched how to work around this issue and found this page:

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

So I created a new application pool just for this webservice and configured the Application Pool identity to have read-only access to the folder containing redirection.config (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config) using the ACL of the folder. (I did this for the folder rather than the file as it seems that more than one file in the folder is required.)

My question therefore is: as long as I restrict access to the webservice properly, are there any security implications with doing this? It seems ok to me but the implications of making the configuration of these customer sites public could be career limiting to say the least!

Thanks,
Owen

**EDIT: Just wondering if I have worded this question properly? So far no-one has taken a stab at answering it so this edit is mainly to bump it ;)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no security expert (so take my words with a pinch of salt), but I would say that there isn't a hard and fast answer on this. However, most probably lean more towards recommending *against* this.

If your requirement is to allow support to see the connections your different sites use, then I see no issue creating a service like this *in general principle*, so long as you are careful.

That said, there are a number of things you should think long and hard about before going ahead with it:

- Could the same be achieved by simply creating a secured share on the Server, and granting your support/devs RO access to that location? That may be more secure than writing your own service.
- If you are doing this via a webservice, you should add security to the service to prevent unauthorised access (I'd probably use windows authentication myself, but that depends on your requirements)
- I would recommend that you ensure that this service is not visible outside your Local network: you don't want someone from the wider web to be able to get onto this
- Use an SSL connection for your service, to prevent packet sniffers being able to snoop on your traffic and retrieve this sensitive information.
- I would recommend stripping out sensitive information from the Connection string before displaying it. At a minimum, I would remove the password. Anyone who needs the password already knows it, or knows how to get it. Anyone who doesn't need it won't be able to get it via this tool. You may also want to strip out all but the last part of the IP, it's not really secure, but it helps obfuscate information that would make it easier to hack.

Above all, you almost certainly want to communicate this to management/the customer, clearly lay out the potential risks, and detail what (if anything) you will do to mitigate it. If they sign off on it after all that, then the responsibility is really with them.

Comment: _If your requirement is to allow support to see the connections your different sites use, then I see no issue creating a service like this in general principle, so long as you are careful._ Thanks Mr Phoenix. I was planning to use all of your suggestions and agree that in general principle this should be OK. However, on consideration, we've decided to use this code to dump the info to a text file locally. Its a nice enough idea but not worth risking anything over it.

Comment: That makes sense. It's better not to risk the chance that someone could get around your restrictions. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Security of the web service should be your last concern, primary concern is **should you even make such a sensitive/confidential data available through a web service?**

**And the answer is straight NO.**

More than security threats there may be quite a few legal implications on doing such a thing. Even if your customer is the sole owner of all the Apps running on their server they themselves may not be free decide about implementing such a functionality, as it may potentially be a threat to sensitive data belonging to their clients. So if you yourself are planning to make such a decision then you can very well imagine the consequences.

Moreover access to the servers and sensitive data like connection strings is restricted for obvious reasons, and that restriction should not be breached under any circumstances.